Record Triggered Flows - Flow Performance of "Formula Evaluates to True" Start Criteria vs Decision Nodes in flow
We are transitioning some process builders to record-triggered flows as not only a much needed tech debt cleanup, but also to help reduce our CPU execution times for processes that are close to hitting limits.
In the start criteria, we have some criteria that isn't directly related to the object (ex. Account.Owner.IsActive), and is not queryable through the standard conditions.
The question is: is it better, performance wise, to address this in the start criteria and use "Formula Evaluates to True" or to add a decision node that checks it? Or if it is negligible for most scenarios, is there a breaking point in complexity where one would be better than the other (ex. if we have several non-Account based criteria that include checking user info, custom settings, etc, or maybe if just had a huge list of start criteria)?

According to the Performance section of the Record-Triggered Automation article on architect.salesforce.com:

Flow also provides entry conditions, which can help dramatically lower the performance impact if they are used to exclude a flow from a record-edit.

This is due to the initialization cost of entering the Flow, which while less than Process Builder is still present. The guidance is clear in that we should be excluding records from entering a Flow (as per your approach of using the Formula Evaluates to True) rather than starting a Flow instance only to exit straight away once you hit the decision node.
